# For spark-phoenix, I don't want to pull the whole data from HBase. Is there any way to pull the data from table according to my condition?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

It is too slow to pull the whole data from Hbase. I only need to process data for one hour.

So I want to know whether I can specify the SQL in config and pull one-hour data like Spark's support to JDBC connection? or it supports push-down and I just need to write the SparkSQL？

I am using phoenix-4.14.1-HBase-1.3.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I find the answer. The phoenix does support push-down. My fault is that I use `substr` at first, which should be replaced by `startsWith` or `like`.

The evidence is shown below.

```
 /*
    This is the buildScan() implementing Spark's PrunedFilteredScan.
    Spark SQL queries with columns or predicates specified will be pushed down
    to us here, and we can pass that on to Phoenix. According to the docs, this
    is an optimization, and the filtering/pruning will be re-evaluated again,
    but this prevents having to load the whole table into Spark first.
  */
  override def buildScan(requiredColumns: Array[String], filters: Array[Filter]): RDD[Row] = {
    new PhoenixRDD(
      sqlContext.sparkContext,
      tableName,
      requiredColumns,
      Some(buildFilter(filters)),
      Some(zkUrl),
      new Configuration(),
      dateAsTimestamp
    ).toDataFrame(sqlContext).rdd
  }
```